# Unable to Run AwesomeProject given in the React-Native getting started page

Tags: reactjs, windows-10, react-native

New to React Native.I was trying to run the project shown on the Getting Started page of React Native. The app builds successfully but when it launches in emulator, it shows error code 500. I have installed the latest version of react Native whichever is delivered 0.59.x I have the latest Node version. All of this is Running on Windows 10 (1809 Build) with Android Studio 3.3.2 64 bit with SDK 23.0.8 installed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You will need to explain your problem here in details.. give code samples as well as ask a specific question that you needs an answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out 0.59 version was just released and had some inherent bugs. Tried with version 0.57 and it works now.